# Can CSS render text twice, in two different fonts or colors?

Tags: css

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2yRa/) the same text is drawn twice:

- first in white, in a solid font
- then in black, in an outline font

The two fonts, Londrina Solid and Londrina Shadow, are designed to have exactly the same metrics and to be used together in this way.

Is there a way to use CSS to achieve this effect without putting two copies of the text into the HTML? (Of course, I don’t want to put a copy of the text into the CSS, either.)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but let me just say, that is a very cool fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five `text-shadow`s is almost identical<sup>1</sup>:

```
text-shadow: 0.03em 0.03em 0 black, -1.25px 0 0 black, 1.25px 0 0 black, 0 -1.25px 0 black, 0 1.25px 0 black;
```

[Here's a demo!](http://dabblet.com/gist/3711421)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Yes, I know this is an oxymoron.</sub>

Comment: Note that (as per my earlier answer that was downvoted?) CSS text-shadow is not compliant on IE versions prior to 10.

Comment: @Sepster: Do you mean "compatible"? `text-shadow` is compliant. It's IE that's not compliant.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using :after and use the content attribute:

```
h1:after, h1 > span.shadow:after {
    content: "Nashville hack day is November 11";
    font-size: 700%;
}
```

And the html could be:

```
<body>
  <h1><span class="shadow"></span></h1>
</body>
```

I realize this could be cumbersome, but at least you'd only have to write the content once.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/W2yRa/2/).

Comment: +1; [you could do that without additional elements or explicit content references too](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/2mcxh/) - not sure how that affects SEO though

Comment: @o.v: My +1 to both of you.  Clever.  I too would be interested in an SEO expert's opinion on this approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to create text shadows, then check out [W3C: Css: text shadows](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html).

These are not compatible with non-compliant IE<10 though.

Comment: If the point of this exercise is to work around the IE compliance issue, let me know and I'll delete this answer ;-) (But maybe state this in the question to be clear).

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this please explain why? Did I do something wrong?